# calling javascript function from another js file in yii2

Tags: javascript, yii2

I have this problem i'm trying to call a function from a js file but got an error " Uncaught ReferenceError: hello is not defined"

```
<?php
  //Note: This code is within a view file (this view file also uses js code from js/details.js)
  $script = <<< JS

    $(document).ready(function(){
    hello();
         });
        JS;
   $this->registerJs($script);
   ?>



  //Note This code is in an external js file (js/cart.js)
 function hello(){
     console.log('hello');
 }
```

i check my page source and below img is my page source
[image]

I was thinking it's hierarchy problem so i place the cart.js above in my asset file but can't still make it work, any help will be apprciated

i'm editing and adding a new img of my console broswer

[image]

Comment: check in browser  console if the js/cart.js is really loaded ..

Comment: are there any errors in your browser console?

Comment: yes the error in console browser is  Uncaught Reference Error: hello is not defined

Comment: see if you have multiple versions of jQuery loading.

Comment: can you wrap the script inside your view in the `$this->registerJs('your-js-code-here',\yii\web\view::POS_END);` an make sure you are not including `jquery` in the head too

Comment: @ Muhammad Omer Aslam  thanks i will try